# how to create an event on google calendar using php

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

am trying to sync. events from my website to **google** **calendar** after

user give me a permission  to write on **calendar** .

am using PHP , **google calendar API not zend framword**

Comment: any body can help , cause i lost my mind......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to read the reference?

Using quickAdd (which creates an event based on a simple string)

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/quickAdd

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$createdEvent = $service->events->quickAdd(
    'primary',
    'Appointment at Somewhere on June 3rd 10am-10:25am');

echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Or using insert

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('attendeeEmail');
// ...
$attendees = array($attendee1,
                   // ...
                  );
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Comment: @Mohammed ok... Their documentation isn't up to date, it seems. try with `Google_Event` instead of `Event`

Comment: you just return me to life .....many thanks, no any documents about this....realy thank

Comment: What does 'primary' stands for in the example? Is it the calenderId?
.....insert('primary', $event);

Comment: @AndreasMattisson yes, it's the calendarId.

Answer (score 1):

The reference seems out of date - the class names are incomplete ([creating google calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152587/creating-google-calendar-event))

Here's the updated snippet:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('attendeeEmail');
// ...
$attendees = array($attendee1,
                   // ...
                  );
$event->attendees = $attendees;

$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);
echo $createdEvent->id;
```

Comment: echo $createdEvent->id not work  write echo $createdEvent['id'] it work perfect...

Comment: *Comment from [user3932650](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3932650/user3932650):* Where you create or initialize `$cal` variable? it's showing error in end.

Answer (score 0):

The way the documentation describes creating events worked nicely for me.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events):

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

Assuming you already know how to [retrieve an access token](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php), a more complete implementation could be the following:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/* Retrieve access token */

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Create Event');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```