# Google Calendar API v3 PHP new event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to do add an event. I use client libraries.
After passing oAuth I get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in zarzadzaj/kursy.php on line 17

My code is:

```
<?php
require_once '../zarzadzaj/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../zarzadzaj/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$start->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$end->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setEnd($end);

$anEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

echo $anEvent->getId();
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840594/how-to-create-an-event-on-google-calendar-using-php Read this..

Comment: @MODEV I don't believe the question linked to is relevant any more. Google has changed their API since then and the solutions in that thread, while helpful as a starting point to finding solutions, may now be outdated. I spent half a day messing with that nonsense before I started realizing it was old code... Goog's docs are apparenly still a mess when it comes to this too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution...
You need to declare '$service' as an instance  of the google calendar service first before you call the insert() method..This worked for me...I hope this works for you too..

```
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);
```

Comment: I get: Class 'Google_CalendarService' not found :(