# Google Calendar API date time

Tags: php, html, api, datetime, calendar

I'm trying to get the Google Calendar Api to work. Without the use of my $_POST date times it works perfect. But then the date is hard coded like the google ones and that is not what i want. When i use my $_POST vars it shows me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=: (400) **Start and end times must either both be date or both be dateTime**.'
```

My dateTime code:

```
  if ($client->getAccessToken()){
  $dt = new DateTime();
  echo $dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000+01:00") . "\n";

  if (isset($_POST['addevent'])){
  echo "<hr><font size=+1>I have access to your calendar</font>";
  $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
  $event->setSummary($_POST['title']);
  $event->setLocation($_POST['location']);
  $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
  $start->setTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');
  $start->setDateTime($dt);
  $event->setStart($start);
  $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
  $end->setDateTime($dt);
  $event->setEnd($end);
  $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('f8ov32gchvan0b6a0594r72jng@group.calendar.google.com', $event);
  echo "<br><font size=+1>Event created</font>";

  echo "<hr><br><font size=+1>Already connected</font> (No need to login)";

  }
```

I'm also experimenting with   `echo $dt->format("c") . "\n";`
which is giving me the same thing only without .000 .
Google Calendar requires me to have a dime time format like:

```
$start->setDateTime('2012-10-31T10:00:00.000-05:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2012-10-31T10:25:00.000-05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
```

Source: [Create Simple Google Calendar Event in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690653/create-simple-google-calendar-event-in-php)

My HTML input fields:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date1">Date1<br>
<input type="datetime-local" name="date2">Date2<br>
```

ATM i'm not using my $_POST i'm checking with

```
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000+01:00") . "\n";
```

So my question is, How do i get the google time format with PHP?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [Google Calendar API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) the required format must follow the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) format. To convert a `DateTime` to this format one can use the [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function in conjunction with the [DateTime::RFC3339](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339) constant.

You should get something like:

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
$calendarDateTime = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$calendarDateTime->setDateTime($dt->format(\DateTime::RFC3339));
```